# Handle Frame by Frame Animation on AnimationDrawable using Swipe Gesture

Tags: android

Hello there fellow developers , 
what i am trying to build is a 3D viewer on Anroid Studio that will , after a short FrameAnimation of around 30 frames , let you handle the frames with a swipe gesture. What i mean is that i want to move through frames of a frameanimation with a swipe gesture. Swiping left will get me back to the previous frames and swiping right will lead me to the next frames. What i have so far is here:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener  {
private ImageView view;
private AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Type casting the Image View
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    // Setting animation_list.xml as the background of the image view
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation_list_intro);

    // Type casting the Animation drawable
    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();

    //set true if you want to animate only once
    frameAnimation.setOneShot(true);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    frameAnimation.start();
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation_list_swipe);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.setOneShot(true);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){

                @Override
                public void onSwipeLeft() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    frameAnimation.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwipeRight() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    frameAnimation.start();
                }
            });
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

OnSwipe Class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/*
Usage:
  myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
    @Override
public void onSwipeDown() {
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
  }
*/
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context c) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureListener());
}

public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    // Determines the fling velocity and then fires the appropriate swipe event accordingly
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeDown();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeUp();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeUp() {
}

public void onSwipeDown() {
}
}
```